# Object Looping in javascript

Tags: javascript

This may be simple question, but i tried a lot and i can't find the solution. My problem is i want to loop through an object  and get the properties of the object.

My object look like this:

```
{ value1: '0.92',
  value2: '3728104',
  value3: '43',
  value4: '0.66',      
}
```

I want to get value1, value2, value3, value4

My code:

```
 console.log("bbbbb=" +util.inspect(results));
        for (var prop in results) {
            console.log("Inside for");----------------------> This is printing once.
            keys.push(prop);
            console.log("After push");--------------------->This is not printed..
        }           
        console.log("keys=" +keys)
```

But its not looping ,, Help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Basic debugging: log `prop` to see what it is

Comment: it should work fine... your code outputs ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"] for console.log(keys); Isnt that what you want..?

Comment: Yes @Sudhir ..i want that but keys is not printing..

Comment: @Subburaj see this:: http://jsfiddle.net/quwLW/

Comment: @sudhir nothing happens there??

Comment: @Subburaj check the console you will see the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function like this

```
console.log(Object.keys(results));
# [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4' ]
```

Actually, your code has no problems at all

```
var results = {
    value1: '0.92',
    value2: '3728104',
    value3: '43',
    value4: '0.66',
};

var keys = [];
for (var prop in results) {
    keys.push(prop);
}

console.log(keys);
# [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4' ]
```

Comment: If i put some console.log() b4 push statement its printing,but nothing below that..

Comment: @Subburaj Please show the actual code you used and show us the output of `console.log(keys)`, after the loop.

Comment: @Subburaj Please try the code I have shown in the answer, as it is.

Comment: Ya that works...I am still confused..i have declared keys array globally.. thats the problem..

Comment: @Subburaj Most likely. Without seeing the actual code and the actual error, that is out best bet.